# iphone unit tests setup problem

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I'm going through the tutorial for setting up logic tests - http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html

When I attempt to build and run, I get this error :
"exited abnormally with code 133 (it may have crashed)."

My unit test is identical to the example -

```
#import "LogicTests.h"

@implementation LogicTests

- (void) testFail {

  STFail(@"Must fail to succeed.");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002330/iphone-unit-test-setup-problems) I made explains why it doesn't act like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly the same as the example given by Apple. I would suggest going through the tutorial again and making sure everything is set correctly. This is not enough information to really give you a solution.