# Implementing Unit Testing with iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ios-simulator

I've followed [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW3) to setup unit testing on my app when I got a little stuck.

At bullet point 8 in that tutorial it shows this image, which is what I should be expecting when I build: [alt text http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/art/logic_test_failure_text_editor.jpg](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/art/logic_test_failure_text_editor.jpg)

However this isn't what I get when I build. I get this error message: `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1` as well as the error message the unit test has created. Then, when I expand on the first error I get this:

```
PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" "build/3D Pool.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicTests.build/Script-1A6BA6AE10F28F40008AC2A8.sh"
cd "/Users/james/Desktop/FYP/3D Pool"
setenv ACTION build
setenv ALTERNATE_GROUP staff
...
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR 0300
setenv XCODE_VERSION_MINOR 0320
setenv YACC /Developer/usr/bin/yacc
/bin/sh -c "\"/Users/james/Desktop/FYP/3D Pool/build/3D Pool.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicTests.build/Script-1A6BA6AE10F28F40008AC2A8.sh\""

/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:412: note: Started tests for architectures 'i386'
/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:419: note: Running tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
objc[12589]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
Test Suite '/Users/james/Desktop/FYP/3D Pool/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicTests.octest(Tests)' started at 2010-01-04 21:05:06 +0000
Test Suite 'LogicTests' started at 2010-01-04 21:05:06 +0000
Test Case '-[LogicTests testFail]' started.
/Users/james/Desktop/FYP/3D Pool/LogicTests.m:17: error: -[LogicTests testFail] : Must fail to succeed.
Test Case '-[LogicTests testFail]' failed (0.000 seconds).
Test Suite 'LogicTests' finished at 2010-01-04 21:05:06 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds

Test Suite '/Users/james/Desktop/FYP/3D Pool/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LogicTests.octest(Tests)' finished at 2010-01-04 21:05:06 +0000.
Executed 1 test, with 1 failure (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.002) seconds

/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:448: error: Failed tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
/Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:462: note: Completed tests for architectures 'i386'
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Now this is very odd as it is running the tests (and succeeding as you can see my STFail firing) because if I add a different test which passes I get no errors, so the tests are working fine. But why am I getting this extra build fail?

It may also be of note that when downloading solutions/templates which should work out the box, I get the same error. I'm guessing I've set something up wrong here but I've just followed a tutorial 100% correctly!

EDIT: According to [this blog](http://www.mcubedsw.com/blog/index.php/site/comments/xcode_3.2_teh_awesome_edition/), [this post](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2009-10/msg00216.html) and a few other websites, I'm not the only one getting this problem. It has been like this since the release of xCode 3.2, assuming the apple dev center documents and tutorials etc are pre-3.2 as well.

However some say its a known issue whereas others seem to think this was intentional. I for one would like both the extended console and in code messages, and I certainly do not like the "Command /bin/sh..." error and really think they would have documented such an update. Hopefully it will be fixed soon anyway.

UPDATE:
Here's confirmation it's something changed since the release of xCode 3.2.1.

This image:
[alt text http://ing0.co.uk/info/pics/unittest-xcode-3.2.1.png](http://ing0.co.uk/info/pics/unittest-xcode-3.2.1.png) is from my test build using 3.2.1. This one is from an older version (3.1.4):
[alt text http://ing0.co.uk/info/pics/unittest-xcode-3.1.4.png](http://ing0.co.uk/info/pics/unittest-xcode-3.1.4.png). (The project for both was unchanged).

Comment: I'm getting this same issue in 3.2.5 (64-bit Intel Core i3, OSX 10.6.6)

Comment: Nice for you to bounty this, but I'm not so sure there will be an answer!

Comment: C'est pas grave, I seem to have tests working.

Answer (score 5):

Double click 'Run script' under 'Targets'/'Your script target name' then type

```
# Run the unit tests in this test bundle. 
"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests" 1> /tmp/RunUnitTests.out
```

Basically you need to append

```
1> /tmp/RunUnitTests.out
```

to what is already there

Comment: Looks like a dead link I'm afraid!

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it for me (and this was driving me crazy up until now!)

Comment: Works for me too, but i used "1> /dev/null" instead since the output in the tmp file won't be looked at anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the build configuration to "Debug" for the test case ?

i did that, as shown at http://nothing2fancy.com/2009/08/04/failed-tests-for-architecture-i386-gc-off/ and it worked

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's not quite what's happening on mine! The unit test's themselves are working fine, it's the message that is supposed to appear in code has gone from the most recent version of xcode, they now appear in the build results but I don't think this is intended! Which version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 3.2.2 Pre-release. so that might be fixed in the latest

Comment: Possibly, I'm still on 3.2.1. Thanks for that, I'll get the current pre-release and give that a go.

Comment: Well, the 3.2 SDK was published yesterday. I didn't try Unit Tests again, but since it worked in the pre-release i'm pretty confident it will work on the stable one ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to check this issue [SenTestCase in Xcode 3.2 and XCBuildLogCommandInvocationSection Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516745/sentestcase-in-xcode-3-2-and-xcbuildlogcommandinvocationsection-errors)

the workaround in that question work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Menu: Project --> New Build Phase --> New RunScript Build Phase --> Paste the following into the empty text area:

`"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests" 1> /tmp/RunUnitTests.out`

Now try to build and you should get an error on failed unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it a right way or not, but it's work for me.

> In General Tab of info Test Case, I
>   add  my main application executable
>   target as a direct dependency.

And no error for ‘i386′ (GC OFF)”.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input but it still does the same thing :(

Answer (score 0):

When you create your firt test case classes, make sure the Target is set to your UnitTest target, not your application target.

If you forget to do this when you create the class, you can "Get Info" on the existing class, and set the target there....

Comment: It's been a while since I tried doing it but I'm sure I did that!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, never played with unit tests in XCode (of course I liked JUnit in good old java times). So it is just a trial: What compiler are you using, GCC or LLVM? Maybe GCC is the better choice to be on the safe side.

Do you have the same behaviour when "Build Active Architecture Only" in Project settings is enabled? This switch removes duplicate error messages when building for armv6 and armv7, maybe it's related.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at apple's latest [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneUnitTests/iPhoneUnitTests.zip). When you download the code there is a read me file in which its clearly written:

```
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Running Logic Tests
To run the logic tests:
1. Choose Project > Set Active Target > CalculatorTests.
2. Choose Project > Set Active SDK > Simulator.
3. Choose Build > Build. Xcode runs the test cases implemented in
   the CalculatorTests.m file.
4. Choose Build > Build Results to open the Build Results window, containing
   the tests results. You may have to click the Show Transcript button (the
   third button on the bottom-left corner of the build results list) to view
   the build transcript.

The logic-tests results look similar to this:

   PhaseScriptExecution <project_directory>/build/iPhoneUnitTests.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalculatorTests.build/Script-17AA84010F99894F00167681.sh
       cd <project_directory>
       /bin/sh -c <project_directory>/build/iPhoneUnitTests.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalculatorTests.build/Script-17AA84010F99894F00167681.sh
   /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:364: note: Started tests for architectures 'i386'
   /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:371: note: Running tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
   objc[1222]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
   objc[1222]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
   Test Suite '<project_directory>/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalculatorTests.octest(Tests)' started at 2009-05-19 16:55:28 -0700
   Test Suite 'CalculatorTests' started at 2009-05-19 16:55:28 -0700
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testAddition] setUp
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testAddition] start
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testAddition] end
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testAddition] tearDown
   Test Case '-[CalculatorTests testAddition]' passed (0.007 seconds).
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testDivision] setUp
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testDivision] start
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testDivision] end
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testDivision] tearDown
   Test Case '-[CalculatorTests testDivision]' passed (0.003 seconds).
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testInputException] setUp
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testInputException] start
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testInputException] end
   <time> otest[1222:80f] -[CalculatorTests testInputException] tearDown
   ...
   Test Case '-[CalculatorTests testSubtractionNegativeResult]' passed (0.002 seconds).
   Test Suite 'CalculatorTests' finished at 2009-05-19 16:55:28 -0700.
   Executed 6 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.021 (0.022) seconds

   Test Suite '<project_directory>/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalculatorTests.octest(Tests)' finished at 2009-05-19 16:55:28 -0700.
   Executed 6 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.021 (0.024) seconds

   /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:388: note: Passed tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
   /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:399: note: Completed tests for architectures 'i386'


Remember that logic tests are executed as part of the build process to provide
you with build errors for failed unit tests. Logic unit-test bundles are not
intented to run in iPhone Simulator or a device.

———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

Hence there is some change in the sentesting kit. I don't think it would be worth for filing a bug.

Comment: @ing0 sorry, didn't notice :( but Boy! the bounty is for 7 days only thats way I answered ;)

Answer (score -4):

That is the expected behavior. The build will fail if one of the tests fail and the build will succeed if all the tests pass.

Comment: You clearly haven't read the post. The unit tests work fine but they are not being displayed as they are supposed to. Check out the screenshots from version 3.2 compared to 3.1.