# Unit testing in Xcode doesn't work like in Apple's example

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Unit Testing on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002330/implementing-unit-testing-on-the-iphone)

I'm trying to follow [Apple's example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) of how to set up unit testing...

I started a new project and followed the directions. Instead of getting an error message inside the code editor (like in step 8), I get two error messages that are shown on the bottom right icon. When I click it, I see the following errors:

> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1.
>   Must fail to succeed.

How can I fix this? Do I need to reinstall Xcode because I might have changed some hard to find setting that fixes this problem?

**Update:**
I tried installing another version of Xcode to another directory, but it didn't help.

I'm using Xcode 3.2.3.

**Update:**
See [Implementing Unit Testing with the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002330/implementing-unit-testing-on-the-iphone)

Comment: I prefer trying with GTM http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/. I cannot make the default unit testing work as well:(