# SenTestCase in Xcode 3.2 and XCBuildLogCommandInvocationSection Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a set of SenTestCase that are causing issues in XCode 3.2.4. When attempting to compile (with a very basic STFail(@"");) the following compiler errors occur:

> An internal error occurred when handling command output: -
> [XCBuildLogCommandInvocationSectionRecorder endMarker]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> An internal error occurred when handling command output: -
> [XCBuildLogCommandInvocationSection setTestsPassedString:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance

I've included the SenTestkingKit.framework from '/Developer/Library/Frameworks' and just created by target by 'Targets > Add > New Target > Cocoa Touch > Unit Test Bundle'. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems to be a regression with some part of the reporting code not respecting timezone issues. The output is tagged as ending before it began, so gets very confused and chokes.

One work-around, that I found somewhere on Google, is to change the Run Script stage of the target.

Change

```
"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
```

to

```
"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests" 1> /tmp/RunUnitTests.out
```

It’s working round the issue, rather than solving it, but does work.

Comment: Hey Andy. Thanks for the hint! Will it still report errors if you redirect STOUT?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. It just doesn’t do the nice nesting of tests as they run, and dumps it all in the build window.

Comment: My Target has no Run Script, hence the first line Andy specifies doesn't exist. I'm looking for the Run Script by expanding the Target and again expanding the project name within the Target. Is this the correct place to look?

Comment: @thebossman If you right-click on the project name within the target, you get the option to Add->New Build Phase->New Run Script Build Phase. So yes, right place, but you may have to add the Run Script itself.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when developing an iPad app. Try changing the Base SDK of your test target from iPhone Device 3.2 to iPhone Device 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was running on 4.1 and changing to 4.0 fixed the issue. Appreciate it!

Comment: Changing the Base SDK fixed the problem for me, using XCode 3.2.3 / SDK 4.0. I changed the separate target for tests to get tests to build, or the changed the main app target (which depends on the tests) for the app to build. Both IiPhone Device 4.0 and iPhone Simulator 4.0 worked. Alternatively changing the project settings (user456331) worked for both. As well as setting the SDK to 4.0, you should also set the iPhone OS Deployment Target to the version you want to be backwards compatible with.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with xcode 3.2.3 and iPad.
This one helps me to solve it:

```
Project -> Edit Project Settings -> Build -> Base SDK = iPhone Device 4.0
Project -> Edit Project Settings -> Build -> iPhone OS Deployment Target = iPhone OS 3.2
```

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be fixed (finally!) in the 4.2 SDK.