# Where is "Run Script" on the target?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to apply this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516745/sentestcase-in-xcode-3-2-and-xcbuildlogcommandinvocationsection-errors) but I cannot find the "Run Script" setting, property, flag?

I can see it in the temporary script file that is created on build.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select target in outline view
2. In the context menu, select "Add..." → "New Build Phase" → "New Run Script Build Phase"
3. A window will appear where you can edit the script

Answer (score 1):

"Run Script" is a stage of the build process for a given target in Xcode. You probably have a target set up for your unit tests: look for it in the Targets section of the Groups & Files pane (Targets is usually pretty far down on the left side of Xcode).

If you expand your unit test target you should see a series of steps that get executed, with icons that look like grey squares: "Copy Bundle Resources", "Compile Sources", etc. One of these should be "Run Script". If it's not there, cmd-click/right-click on the target and select Add → New Build Phase → New Run Script Build Phase.

If you cmd-click/right-click on the Run Script build phase and select Get Info, under the General tab should be a Script section. Paste the workaround in there.