# Xcode 4: dyld error running unit tests from command line

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line-interface, ocunit

Following the instructions [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/running-xcode-4-unit-tests-from-the-command-line/) I setup a test target to run my OCUnit test cases from the command line.

The tests work in Xcode via cmd-U, however they don't work in the Terminal.  Running them, I get this error:

> ```
> /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:419: note: Running tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
> 2011-10-19 12:21:36.746 otest[63517:7803] The test bundle at /Users/ben/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Deli-gspotoqkkxdkiqddximbbiwaivvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/deliappTests.octest
> could not be loaded because a link error occurred.  It is likely that
> dyld cannot locate a framework framework or library that the the test
> bundle was linked against, possibly because the framework or library
> had an incorrect install path at link time.
> /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:448: error: Failed tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
>
> /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:462: note: Completed tests for architectures 'i386'
>
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
> ```

I created a sample app & followed the same steps, and it worked just fine.  It must be a linker issue with my current project.

I don't have any insight into which library or framework it can't find, so it's very difficult to debug.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be very similar to the question asked in the following.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002330/implementing-unit-testing-with-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: That's a different question entirely.